# The type ''a list' does not support the operator '+'

Tags: f#, functional-programming, type-inference, currying

`auxInner` below returns an int list. But when I call `List.sum(auxInner xs ys)` within the subsequent `inner` function I get this weird error! Doesn't `List.sum` take int lists?

```
let rec auxInner xs ys =
    match (xs, ys) with
    |([],[]) -> []
    |([], ys) -> ys
    |(xs, []) -> xs
    |(x::xs, y::ys) -> x*y::auxInner xs ys

let rec inner xs ys = 
    match (xs, ys) with
    |([],[]) -> []
    |([], ys) -> ys
    |(xs, []) -> xs
    |(xs, ys) -> List.sum(auxInner xs ys)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other pattern of `inner` return a list so `List.sum(auxInner xs ys)` has to return a list too.
On the other hand List.sum uses some defined (+) over the type to do it's summation.
And that summation has to be a list as said previously, so we need a way to sum lists somehow.
As there is no (+) defined for lists you get that error message.

There is great chance you either have to returns an int in each case of the match or to returns a list in each case, maybe a singleton `[List.sum (auxInner xs ys)]` but without context...

Comment: Thanks! I changed it so that each pattern returns an int and not a list, so now it works.